# Kubernetes deployment patterns & REST API versions

Tags: rest, kubernetes, devops

I have a REST API with multiple API-versions. Each API backend is composed of several micro-services. It is fair to assume that only the latest REST API resources/code has most churn. The older versions will see churn due to feature backport (rarely) or bug fixes (mostly). I'd like to get recommendations on what DevOps pattern would best fit this scenario - assuming we are using Kubernetes to model our service mesh.

Note that our APIs are mostly async and so it is possible to support several API versions all in the same codebase (packaged in a single container).

Given the above, these configurations are all possible

- Service yaml per API version.
- Single service yaml with multiple pod templates (one per API version).
- Functional Service yamls - one for the front end and each of the other micro-services (POD for message broker, processing worker  etc.,).

Additional points to ponder:

- Are deployments recommended to separate clusters or to the same cluster (for the API versions). If yes, does this impact updates to specific API versions?

I'm looking for any prescribed patterns or suggestions based on your prior experience.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Deployments manage replicas of Pods, and each Pod runs a specific container image. If your API backend consists of multiple microservices, then each microservice is a Deployment. The microservice that handles API requests is exposed with a (client-facing) Service.

For the multiple API versions, you could just replicate this for each version and you could put an Ingress in front of the Services which routes traffic to one of them based on the requested API version.

If you put all the API versions in the same container, you may have a problem of inconsistent state during updates: 1) inside a Deployment, for a short time both Pod versions exist side by side (if you use the default rolling update); 2) for a short time you might have both updated and not yet updated microservices next to each other.

Comment: If I understood this right, your suggestion is to have each micro-service as a separate Deployment (so they can scaled with replicas independently) and a set of Services per API version for the microservice that handles client requests fronted by an ingress Gateway. This makes sense. Will there be a problem if there are multi-container PODS? I expect most of our Deployments and Services to contain at least a FluentD/Logging sidecar.

Comment: Yes, right. Note that also the microservices that don't handle client requests need a Service (of type ClusterIP) so that they can be accessed by other microservices. There's no problem with sidecar containers in the Pods. It's just part of the Pod and a Pod is a unit.